# 400 bad request when submitting form with Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

When i submit a form i get 400 bad request with message "Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand." The html form submits method post to same page.  Where did i go wrong?

Here is my code:

```
APP_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

@app.route('/create/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create():
    if request.method=='POST':
        title=request.form['title']
        description=request.form['description']
        slug=request.form['slug']
        published=request.form['published']
        youtube=request.form['youtube']
        meta_keywords=request.form['meta_keywords']

        destination = APP_DIR + '/images/'
        poster = request.files['poster']
        poster.save(destination + secure_filename(poster.filename))
        poster_filename = poster.filename
        thumbnail = request.files['thumbnail']
        thumbnail.save(destination + secure_filename(thumbnail.filename))
        thumbnail_filename = thumbnail.filename

        connection = mysql.get_db()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query="INSERT INTO videos(title,description,slug,published,youtube,meta_keywords,poster,thumbnail) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(query,(title,description,slug,published,youtube,meta_keywords,poster_filename,thumbnail_filename))
        connection.commit()
        return render_template('create.html')
    else:
        return render_template('create.html')
```

Comment: You should turn the debugger on and inspect that output. The 400 doesn't really help determine what went wrong.

Comment: Please show us the html code of the form.